# How to Remove unwanted Style attributes from HTML String Using PHP DOMDocument

Tags: php, xss, domdocument

I have prepared a white list of allowed styles and I want to remove all the styles out of the white list from HTML String

```
$allowed_styles = array('font-size','color','font-family','text-align','margin-left');
$html = 'xyz html';
$html_string = '<bdoy>' . $html . '<body>';
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html_string);
$elements = $dom->getElementsByTagName('body');
foreach($elements as $element) {

foreach($element->childNodes as $child) {

if($child->hasAttribute('style')) {

$style = strtolower(trim($child->getAttribute('style')));

//match and get only the CSS Property name
preg_match_all('/(?<names>[a-z\-]+):/', $style, $matches);

for($i=0;$i<sizeof($matches["names"]);$i++) {

  $style_property = $matches["names"][$i];

  // if the css-property is not in allowed styles array
  // then remove the whole style tag from this child

  if(!in_array($style_property,$allowed_styles)) {

   $child->removeAttribute('style');
   continue;

   }

}

    }
  }
}

$dom->saveHTML();
$html_output = $dom->getElementsByTagName('body');
```

I have tested so many html strings, it works fine every where. But When I tried to filter this html string

```
$html_string = ​'<div style="font-style: italic; text-align: center; 
background-color: red;">On The Contrary</div><span 
style="font-style: italic; background-color: rgb(244, 249, 255); 
font-size: 32px;"><b style="text-align: center; 
background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">This is USA</b></span>';
```

All other un allowed styles are removed from this string except this line

```
<b style="text-align: center; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">
```

Can Some one tell me any other efficient and robust way to remove the styles other than the whitelist

Answer (score 2):

Similar to Oleja solution, but this one removes only unallowed properties, not whole style attribute.

```
//$this->removeStylesheet($doc, ['color','font-weight']);

function removeStylesheet($tree, $allowed_styles) {
    if ($tree->nodeType != XML_TEXT_NODE) {
        if ($tree->hasAttribute('style')) {
            $style = strtolower(trim($tree->getAttribute('style')));
            preg_match_all('/(?<names>[a-z\-]+) *:(?<values>[^\'";]+)/', $style, $matches);
            $new_styles = array();
            for ($i=0; $i<sizeof($matches['names']); $i++) {
                if(in_array($matches['names'][$i], $allowed_styles)) {
                    $new_styles[] = $matches['names'][$i].':'.$matches['values'][$i];
                }
            }
            if ($new_styles)
                $tree->setAttribute('style', implode(';', $new_styles));
            else
                $tree->removeAttribute('style');
        }
        if ($tree->childNodes) {
            foreach ($tree->childNodes as $child) {
                $this->removeStylesheet($child, $allowed_styles);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For this (and other nested) html you must use recursive function like this:

```
$html = 'your html';
$allowed_styles = array('font-size','color','font-family','text-align','margin-left');
$html_string = '<body>' . $html . '</body>';
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html_string);
$elements = $dom->getElementsByTagName('body');
foreach ($elements as $element)
    clearHtml($element, $allowed_styles);
$html_output = $dom->saveHTML(); 

function clearHtml($tree, $allowed_styles) {
    if ($tree->nodeType != XML_TEXT_NODE) {
        if ($tree->hasAttribute('style')) {
            $style = strtolower(trim($tree->getAttribute('style')));
            preg_match_all('/(?<names>[a-z\-]+):/', $style, $matches);
            for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($matches['names']); $i++) {
                $style_property = $matches['names'][$i];
                if(!in_array($style_property, $allowed_styles)) {
                    $tree->removeAttribute('style');
                    continue;
                }
            }
        }
        if ($tree->childNodes)
            foreach ($tree->childNodes as $child)
                clearHtml($child, $allowed_styles);
    }
}
```